# Getting element position/offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with images, and I need to add an icon to the corner of each image (so that the center of the icon matches the corner). I managed to do that with css relative position, but since the icons are partially outside cells, they mess up the table.

Now I'm trying to add the icons outside the table, and set their position from there. However, I'd like to avoid hardcoding the positions of the images, and determine it on the fly. But using `.offsetLeft` and jQuery's `offset()` both return 0, apparently because the elements are positioned automatically. Is there really no way to determine the element's exact position in this case?

Comment: jQuery has a `.position()` method and two versions of the `.offset()` method, if I'm not mistaken. None of them work for you? If you really want help, you'll need to show your code, markup and styling. A jsFiddle would be your best bet.

Comment: You really dont need javascript for this. If you put up a fiddle with the html/css you tried, we can help you get a pure css solution.

Answer (score 1):

to make it with js it's longer and complicated, i advice you to make it with css and for the problem of the icons you can use overflow:hidden so that the icons don't be shown outside of the cells

For example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/CdLEm/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="corner"></div>
</div>


#container {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid #222;
}
#corner {
    position:absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top:-13px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#FF0000;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```